# How can I cut the excess rectangle off of this image using Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I used a clipping mask to fill the outer circle with a glitter image. It won't allow me to make another clipping mask. So I'm at a loss as to how to do this. I'm new to Illustrator so please be detailed about the steps in your response.

Comment: Which excess rectangle are you talking about? The pink-purple (fuchsia? lavender?) one behind the front-most circle? Or the dark grey background? Or the white background? I’m guessing you only have the image as raster (JPEG/PNG/similar) so the obvious technique of selecting the offending object and just deleting it is unavailable?

Comment: the pink one. And no I made this entire image in illustrator myself. I only want to delete the part of the rectangle that hangs over the edge of the circle.

Comment: Oh, you want the left and right edges of the pink rectangle to flush with the edge of the glitter-black circle, making it visually a non-rectangle? I would intersect the two shapes, then, getting rid of the non-overlapping area.

Comment: That sounds like what I want to do! Lol now.....about the actual how of how to do that

Comment: One word: [pathfinder tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html) (okay, one compound word).

Answer (score 1):

1. Release the clipping mask that contains the glitter
2. Group the pink and glitter together on the same layer
3. Re-create the clipping mask with the grouped glitter/pink item

Answer (score 0):

Cut the pink. -- Select it and choose `Edit > Cut`

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to click the "glitter"

Choose `Edit > Paste in Front`

This should place the pink items *inside* the same clipping mask used for the "glitter".

Beyond this, you'll need to show a screen shot of the Layers Panel *expanded* to show the objects and their layers to help any further.